# Using Reflection to discover an objects property list

Tags: c#, reflection

I've tried for 2 days to find something that will work and none of the examples I have found are working.

What I need is to be able to get a list of public properties from an instantiated class.

For Instance:

MyClass has the following definition:

```
public class MyClassSample : MyDC
{
  public string ReportNumber = "";
  public string ReportDate = "";

  public MyClassSample()
  {
  }
}
```

What I need is a way to simply return an array that has ["ReportNumber"]["ReportDate"] in it from the above class.

Here is my most recent attempt, just to add the property names to a string:

```
    string cMMT = "";

    Type t = atype.GetType();
    PropertyInfo[] props = t.GetProperties();
    List<string> propNames = new List<string>();
    foreach (PropertyInfo prp in props)
    {
        cMMT = cMMT + prp.Name + "\n";
    }
```

I think I am missing something basic and simple, but for some reason I cannot see it right now.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you learn the difference between fields and properties before you dive into reflection ;)

Comment: Please read also this article how to handle with String http://www.dotnetperls.com/convert-list-string

Answer (score 6):

Those aren't properties. Those are fields.

So you can do this:

```
FieldInfo[] fields = t.GetFields();
```

Or you can change those into properties:

```
public string ReportNumber { get; set; }
public string ReportDate { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
public string ReportNumber = "";
public string ReportDate = "";
```

to this

```
public string ReportNumber { get; set; }
public string ReportDate { get; set; }
```

and then,

```
List<string> propNames = new List<string>();

foreach (var info in atype.GetType().GetProperties())
{
   propNames.Add(info.Name);
}
```

The result wold be a list (propName) with two positions with the name of your properties